# How can I control a power MOSFET with a logic level MOSFET?

Tags: mosfet

I want to drive a power MOSFET with a logic level one.

Is this circuit possible? If not, please can you explain why?

Below is what I've come up with so far. Note that all the values are made up and that M2 is actually eight IRF530 power MOSFETs connected in parallel.

[image: diagram]

Comment: Both of your FETs appear to be power FETs.  Neither appears to be logic level.  Regardless, you are using both of them as high side switches, which makes them into [source followers.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_drain)  Each source will be a couple of volts below the gate voltage.  Since you are driving both gates from 5V, the source on M2 will be 1V or less.

Comment: How much current does your load really need?

Comment: I making (or trying at least) a spot welder which use around 500 amp or more for a fraction of time. Sorry for my mistake the M1 is IRLZ44N. I will check the sorce followers topology out. Thank for the reply.

Comment: Google reviews of spot welders.  There are videos out there showing what is in them and how it works.  Would be simpler and cheaper just to buy one though.

Comment: I use a single 2N5551 for driving 5 MOSFETS (IRFZ44, paralleled)

Comment: A warm welcome to the site. English may be your first language (it reads like it), it may not. Please make every effort to write a question with good spelling and grammar. The better the quality of your question, the better the quality of the answers it will attract and the better your long-term prospects in engineering. Thanks.

Comment: You can install GRAMMARLY for help ... :-)

Comment: Yeah, use grammarly to get sentences with properly spelled words that don't mean what you were trying to say.  I don't like those stupid things.

Comment: Sometimes, it really helps ... not always ... ok

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTTYEX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here is a simple way to quickly drive 5 power MOSFETs in parallel. M1 is a TO-92 MOSFET, Q1 and Q2 are TO-92 BJTs. Switching time is maybe 50-100ns and power dissipation is about 28W per IRF3710 MOSFET when on.

Comment: I'm curious about the role of Q1 and Q2, what keywords should I Google?

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick "Emitter follower" maybe? Or "class B amplifier", or "gate driver", or "current amplifier"?

Comment: Q1 and Q2 are emitter followers (no voltage gain, but a couple orders of magnitude current gain). Q2 exists to drive charge into the power MOSFET gates, and Q1 is intended to suck it out.  M1 level shifts the 5V input to 10V (voltage gain) but would be slow driving the MOSFETs into the on state if you connected the gates directly to M1 drain because all the charge (about 650 nC) has to pass through R1.

Comment: You could probably get similar performance by replacing Q1 with a fast diode since M1 has a fairly low Rds(on).